# What is the @return_value of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Yesterday I created a stored procedure and it returns the value 98, -1 which I have no idea what it is.

I tried to find the meaning of those but found only that 0 is the successful execution code.

What is the meaning of `@return_value 98` and `@return_value -1`

Here's what I'm talking about.

[image: @return_value 98]

[image: @return_value -1]

Comment: There is no intrinsic meaning, its down to whoever wrote that SP as to what the return values mean. Why don't you just script the SP and see if there is an explanation?

Comment: View the code of the stored procedure you are running to understand the meaning of the value returned by the `RETURN` statement.

Comment: Hang on, you said "Yesterday I created a SP" - so you must have returned those values?

Comment: Actually those values aren't return values, only the last one is where the column name is "Return Value". All the other values come from select statements within the SP.

Comment: Thank you to all help. I see. Yes the value with no column name come from select statement. It's the "select @var=val from table" that return those value. And I still can't figure out what is return value mean from looking in those RETURN statement (This SP calls other SPs which are not return value but it also call functions which return value) So, it might take sometime for me to understand.

Comment: `select @var=val from table` will *never* return a value, thats an assignment - there must be some straight `select val from table` statements in your SP. The *convention* is that a non-zero return value means an error. However you would need the code to know *what* the error is. And some people use the return value to return an `int` (instead of using an output parameter). All this can only be determined by seeing the code.

Comment: Also I found that there's some try... catch... in SP and it always catch error but if I remove the error and those try catch, the code -1 gone and the SP return 0. I guess those are related together.

Answer (score 2):

The "return value" of a stored procedure is just whatever value you return inside the stored procedure code using the `return` statement. If you don't have an explicit `return` statement, then the procedure will return  a value of zero.

Let's look at some examples. In the first example, I use an explicit return statement. I tell the procedure to return the value `1000`:

```
create or alter procedure p as begin
    set nocount on;
    return 1000; -- whatever value I want it to be
end
go

declare @returnvalue int; 
exec @returnvalue = p;
print concat('return value was ',@returnvalue); -- prints "return value was 1000"
go
```

This time I have commented out the return statement. The procedure will return the default value of zero:

```
create or alter procedure p as begin
    set nocount on;
    -- return 1000; comment out the return -> no explicit return value
end
go

-- this code will print "return value was 0" because that's the default
declare @returnvalue int; 
exec @returnvalue = p;
print concat('return value was ', @returnvalue); 
go
```

We can use the return value however we like, but *by convention* return values are used to provide information about the success or failure of the procedure. You *could* use it to return "data", but for that you should use output parameters instead.

In the example below you can see a pretty standard pattern. If no error occurs, we will get to the bottom of the `try` block, and hit the `return 0` statement. Why zero? It's just a convention dating back decades, which means "nothing went wrong, there is no meaningful error to report".

But in the code below I deliberately do something that will cause an error. This means we won't get to the `return 0` statement at the end of the `try` block.

Instead, execution will jump to the `catch` block. Inside the `catch` block I return the value of the `error_number()` associated with the error I deliberately caused.

```
create or alter procedure p as begin
    set nocount on;
    begin try
        -- deliberately do something that will cause an error
        declare @i int = 'abc';
        return 0; -- by pure convention, a return value of 0 means no error.
    end try begin catch
        print error_message();
        return error_number(); -- will be 245 because that's the error number of a conversion failure
    end catch
end
go

-- prints:
-- Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'abc' to data type int.
-- return value was 245
declare @returnvalue int; 
exec @returnvalue = p;
print concat('return value was ', @returnvalue); 
go
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to revisit the stored procedure logic, which you have written. You need to be very clear on what you are returning.

Below are some of the best practices:

- Use RETURN for only returning execution status of the procedure execution. Don’t return any value, other than the procedure execution status.
- For returning scalar values from procedure, use OUTPUT parameter
- For returning multiple values/resultset from procedure, use SELECT statement.